# Stream data from Android device to desktop computer when they are connected to different networks (Android WiFi, computer Ethernet)?

Tags: android, networking, android-sensors, data-stream

I am trying to make an android application that will stream live sensor data (e.g. accelerometer, etc) from my android device to my desktop computer.

My android device is connected to a WiFi network and my desktop computer is connected to a network with an Ethernet cable.

There are android applications available that send data from an android device to a PC via WiFi, but both devices must be connected to the same network.

Is there a way to transfer data if the two devices are connected to different networks?

Thank you!

Comment: if your pc is connected to the same router (or over different switches to the router which gives the wifi signal to the phone) it's still the same network. (except you enabled something like client isolation)

Comment: It is not the same network, because the Ethernet goes to a router in my office, but the wireless network is provided by another transmitter (a central one for the university).

Comment: Would Bluetooth be an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that nearly every network sits behind a firewall (in most cases your home router/nat-device) you need to implement port-forwarding to access network 2 from network 1.

Another aproach would be to set up a VPN (f.i. with SSH) between the 2 hosts.

If your PC is directly connected to the internet, and has a public ip (that means, if you have NOT a RFC 1918 Adress), then you are able to directly connect to that ip by just entering that ip. If not, you need to implement something to get behind the firewall.

Comment: Hi Dominik. I went along a whole different route after all, but I did use ports in the end. My ultimate goal was to send data into a processing sketch, so what I did was that I used the oscP5 library and managed very easily to send the sensor data between the two machines. I uploaded it on my github [link](https://github.com/mandarini/RemoteObserver)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer; to stream data between a PC and an Android device each residing on different networks you need an intermediate server to pass the data through.

Now, if this just a small app that you are doing for your own purpose I suggest using the free version of Firebase (see https://www.firebase.com/). Their sample application that you'll find there, a simple chat service, does pretty much exactly what you need. Simply let the application on your PC (preferably a web app) read the "messages" that you send from your Android device.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your answer, I did not try it but i t must work since both devices would be using an online third-party server. I am trying something different and I will post my solution (if I find one that suits me better).